# Error : py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, pyspark

i am using Pyspark 3.4.1, java 8, hadoop 3.4.0, scala 2.12.17, python 3.11.4 and this is my code in vscode :

```
def calculating_click(df):
    click_data = df.filter((df.custom_track == "click"))
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'bid':0})
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'job_id':0})
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'publisher_id':0})
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'group_id':0})
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'campaign_id':0})
    click_data = click_data.na.fill({'campaign_id':0})
    click_data.registerTempTable('clicks') #name temporary table 'clicks'
    click_output = spark.sql("""select job_id,date(ts) as date,hour(ts) as hour,publisher_id,campaign_id,group_id, avg(bid) as bid_set,count(*) as clicks, sum(bid) as spend_hour from clicks`group by job_id, date(ts), hour(ts),publisher_id, campaign_id, group_id """)`
```

I got this error :

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o28.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:321)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:329)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
Could anyone help me fix this ?
I'm trying using pyspark but got error every time, which version of spark,hadoop,java should i use ?

Comment: Please use the correct [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and do not use images for code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: I just ran into this as well, and the recency of this question makes me think it may be a version mismatch issue caused by a recent release. I'll debug this and report back if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand Spark very well, but I was able to fix this issue by upgrading Spark. The version numbers of PySpark and Spark itself matched exactly both times it was working for me, which makes me think they may have to be kept in lockstep -- perhaps someone else can confirm this.

I had previously used PySpark 3.4.1 with Spark 3.4.1. I just upgraded PySpark to 3.5.0 and saw this error with Spark 3.4.1. Upgrading Spark itself to 3.5.0 resolved it.