# py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark. I am getting this error when i try to run pyspark through jupyter notebook on my hadoop masternode.

Using
Apache spark = 3.4.0
python 3.11

Please check the code given below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("YourAppName") \
    .config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url", "jdbc:hive2://{IP}:{PORT}/{SCHEMA};user={USER};password={PWD}") \
    .config("spark.master", "spark://{IP}:{PORT}") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()
```

This is the error I got.

```
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py:1631, in SparkSession.sql(self, sqlQuery, args, **kwargs)
   1627         assert self._jvm is not None
   1628         litArgs = self._jvm.PythonUtils.toArray(
   1629             [_to_java_column(lit(v)) for v in (args or [])]
   1630         )
-> 1631     return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery, litArgs), self)
   1632 finally:
   1633     if len(kwargs) > 0:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:330, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326         raise Py4JJavaError(
    327             "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328             format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329     else:
--> 330         raise Py4JError(
    331             "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332             format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333 else:
    334     raise Py4JError(
    335         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
    336         format(target_id, ".", name))

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o40.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:321)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:329)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I was able to connect with the hive table using another vm but using the masternode is a requirement

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487178/error-py4j-py4jexception-method-sqlclass-java-lang-string-class-ljava-lan

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I tried matching the same version of Spark and PySpark. The error disappeared but now I am not able to see the data in the table.