# What are compatible versions of pyspark and py4j packages in python

Tags: pyspark, py4j

I am trying to setup pyspark locally

1. I've initiated a spark session
2. created a view named people
3. tried to read the view via below command

```
spark.sql("Select * From people")
```

It throws the Py4j exception below; it seems like a version mismatch error:

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
> Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

1. Spark version: 3.3.4
2. Java version: 20.0.2
3. Python: 3.11.5
4. Pyspark: 3.5.0
5. Py4j: 0.10.9.7

I've tried different versions of Pyspark and Py4j for compatibility but they didn't work.

Comment: Most likely it is the java version : For pyspark version 3.5.0 release notes are here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/   Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.8+, and R 3.5+. Java 8 prior to version 8u371 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.5.0.  Basically downgrade your java version to 17. Pyspark can run independently. it doesn't need a spark installation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the approach in this question: [Error : py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487178/error-py4j-py4jexception-method-sqlclass-java-lang-string-class-ljava-lan)

The root cause of your error seems a mismatch between spark and pyspark.

I would do the following:

**1. Install the same version of pyspark and spark:**

```
python -m pip install pyspark==3.3.4
```

**2. Try your query again**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
# Your code for creating the 'people' view or other operations

# Now try your SQL query again
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people").show()
```